# jQuery text animation "explosion" effect on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, text

Trying to replicate this awesome "Mouse over Escape" effect from the link below using simple jQuery: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-text-animation/full_screen_preview/233445

Any pointers or tips? See "Mouse over Escape" section in link above.

Comment: Features from the codecanyon site seem to work alright in chrome.

Comment: Great effect! Where can I buy it? Wait, you provided the link! How convenient. Thanks. -1

Comment: The idea was to understand how it works without buying it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple jQuery code I wrote:

```js
// jQuery explode text by Aziz Natour
// CC BY 4.0 License
// http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

$('.explodeMe').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(text.replace(/./g, "<span>$&</span>")); 
});
$('.explodeMe span').each(function() {
var min = -10, max = 10,
    min2 = -30, max2 = 30,
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
    random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max2 - min2 + 1)) + min2,
    css = "top:"+random+"px; left:"+random2+"px",
    el = $(this);
    el.on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            el.attr("style", css);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
             el.removeAttr("style");
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.explodeMe span {
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s .1s;
  top:0;left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="explodeMe">I get nervous around cursors.</span>
```

Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/azizn/full/redbRa

**The logic:**

1. Wrap each textual character inside a `<span>` tag
2. Make the new span tags relatively positioned to manipulate their location without affecting layout flow.
3. Apply randomized CSS style to each span separately (for dynamic movement) on hover
4. Remove the style after a delay

The position change is animated using the CSS `transition` property.

Comment: Aziz, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much, i will continue to dabble with it.